# Move AD users with profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7

We are in process of merging our acquired company. We would need to move all users to our domain but also ensure the profile of the existing desktops and laptops do not change. We have computer running on XP and windows 7.

Is there an automated way or script which we can have on the old domain logon script to save user profile disjoin domain join domain and activate the save user profile?

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 5):

You want [ADMT](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8377). It's highly automatable, and is the only supported way that I'm aware of to do what you need to do.

If you need details, you should read here to get started: https://serverfault.com/a/331214/10472

It's also very [well documented](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19188).