# Migrate WinServer 2012R2 to 2022 + Exch 2013 to 19

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, exchange-migration, windows-server-2022

Friends, I have an environment with Windows Server 2012 R2 + MS Exchange 2013. I need to migrate 2012R2 to 2022 and migrate Exchange 2013 to 2019. Is it possible to migrate 2012R2 to 2022 and then immediately migrate Ex2013 to Ex2019?

What should be the correct order of steps?

Add 2022 as DC and then install EXCH2019 pointing to DC2022 and only then upgrade AD function levels?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, from Exchange side, firstly check the supportability matrix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#supported-active-directory-environments  . And the details for your deployment, take a look at the link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-deployment-assistant?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly upgrade '12 to '22, you can however do an intermediate upgrade to a latter version of server 19 and do it.

However that is not the path I would suggest. Migrate is relative.
Is the system only an exchange server, does it hold other roles?

If only an exchange server, I would start a clean install, configure and test your new system until you feel comfortable cutting over.

If it has other roles there are still other paths. Of varied complication,I would not speculate until they are detailed.

IMO as fast as servers deploy this day in time, and in place upgrade is a last resort. Albeit they can be completely fine, the flip side of that is most systems are a different species than the creature that was installed, been through a lot of configs, and possibly admins... NO upgrade can account for everything, and they are known for biting people that dare to believe otherwise.

IF you can give us more details on the environment, we could likely suggest more depending.

Edit: I missed that last line...
In that case I would almost definitely start clean, add the second server as an domain controller, do exchange and configure it, test till time to cut over. The after all is confirmed, transfer all FSMO roles to the new DC, and demote the old.

IF the domain is large and complex,if not I would go with second clean install of everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sabre. My AD has only 60 users and Exchange is used only as mailboxes. Maybe add WinServer2022 as a DC in the existing domain that is WinServer2012 just to ensure the collection of users/credentials, otherwise, if I make a new domain, I'll have to remove all computers from the existing domain, one by one, and then point the new DNS and they enter the new one.
As for Exchange, as it's just mailboxes, I could archive all mailboxes manually, one by one, and recreate the mailboxes in the clean install of Exchange. Given that, what's your opinion? Thanks for the support.

Comment: If you make the second a domain controller in the same domain, it will have a replica of the AD in it, it will just not be the FSOM, that can be transferred to the new DC making the old basically the second and the new primary. Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/view-transfer-fsmo-roles. Same with the exchange server, you can install two exchange servers, here is a decent set of details on that.  https://www.alitajran.com/install-second-exchange-server-in-domain/ After demote the other DC, and when ready point to the new exchange server/remove old.

Comment: I ran out of characters, but doing it that way, you retain the same domain, you are only swapping domain controllers. Meaning users/computers move with it :-)If you create new, you can still move them using ADMT https://serverfault.com/questions/322836/child-domain-migration-to-parent-domain